# Best approximation for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^n\ln\ln k$?

Tags: summation, logarithms

I need the best approximation for 
$\displaystyle{\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\ln\left(\ln\left(k\right)\right)}$. Any suggestion or hint is welcomed.

I derived $n\ln\left(\ln\left(n!\right) \over n\right)$ so is there any better one ?

Comment: If you approximate the sum with an integral, you get $n\log n - \operatorname{Li}(n)$ plus constants. That should be a pretty good approximation.

Comment: Nope. That I could do in my head. To get decent values of the constants, I would need paper and some time, but the main term is easy.

Comment: Sorry for that, but please dont go for 'decent values of the constants, ' instead can you find approximation w/o integral (or similar) function.?

Comment: Why shouldn't one use an intermediate integral? It's the quickest way to get a goodish approximation, and usually allows to estimate the error introduced by exchanging the sum for the integral pretty well. If your problem is with $\operatorname{Li}$, one can approximate that decently with an asymptotic expansion, or a "power series" in $\log x$.

Comment: yeah its true, but can we derive something similar to what i had derived above, that would be great ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler-Maclaurin series:
$$ \sum_{k=2}^n \ln(\ln(k)) = C + \int_2^n \ln(\ln(t))\ dt + \dfrac{1}{2} \ln(\ln(n)) + \dfrac{1}{12 n \ln(n)} - \dfrac{1}{360 n^3 \ln(n)} - \dfrac{1}{240 n^3 \ln(n)^2} - \dfrac{1}{360 n^3 \ln(n)^3} + O(1/n^5) $$
for some constant $C$,
where $$\eqalign{\int_2^n \ln(\ln(t))\ dt &= n \ln(\ln(n)) - 2 \ln(\ln(2)) - \int_2^n \dfrac{dt}{\ln(t)}\cr &= n \ln(\ln(n)) - Li(n) - 2 \ln(\ln(2)) + Li(2)\cr}$$
Numerically it appears $C \approx -.2412388$.

Comment: gr8, I was wondering about any elementary solution but this also can be used for my task.

Comment: please do have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581855/can-anyone-prove-lix12-elix2-e

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
With ${\it\mbox{Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula}}$:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{k}}
=\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}} + \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 2}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{k + 2}}
\\[3mm]&\approx
\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}} + \int_{0}^{n - 1}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{x + 2}}\,\dd x
-
{1 \over 2}\braces{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{0 + 2}}
+ \ln\pars{\ln\pars{\bracks{n - 1} + 2}}}
\\[3mm]&+ {1 \over 12}\braces{%
{1 \over \bracks{\pars{n - 1} + 2}\ln\pars{\bracks{n - 1} + 2}}
-
{1 \over \bracks{0 + 2}\ln\pars{0 + 2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\ln\pars{2}} - { 1 \over 24\ln\pars{2}} + \int_{0}^{n - 1}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{x + 2}}\,\dd x
-
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{\ln\pars{n + 1}} + {1 \over 12\pars{n + 1}\ln\pars{n + 1}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Series. The first few terms are
$$
\int_2^n\log(\log(x))\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac12\log(\log(n))+C+\frac1{12n\log(n)}+\dots
$$
We won't worry about any terms past the first since we need to approximate the integral asymptotically, and the terms in that expansion are bigger than $\log(\log(n))$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int\log(\log(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}e^u\\
&=e^u\log(u)-\int\frac{e^u}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^u\log(u)-\frac{e^u}{u}-\int\frac{e^u}{u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^u\log(u)-\frac{e^u}{u}-\frac{e^u}{u^2}-2\int\frac{e^u}{u^3}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^u\log(u)-\frac{e^u}{u}-\frac{e^u}{u^2}-2\frac{e^u}{u^3}-6\int\frac{e^u}{u^4}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^u\log(u)-\frac{e^u}{u}-\frac{e^u}{u^2}-2\frac{e^u}{u^3}-6\frac{e^u}{u^4}-24\int\frac{e^u}{u^5}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$
From this, we get the asymptotic expansion
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\log(\log(k))\sim n\log(\log(n))-\frac{n}{\log(n)}\left(1+\frac1{\log(n)}+\frac2{\log(n)^2}+\frac6{\log(n)^3}+\dots\right)
$$

Comment: thanks for taking time but this can be achieved even by approximating x! (in my Question) by x^x (which we all know is a poor one !).

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava: the error in using this approximation is less, but it is not as close as using Li for the integral. Using Li, we can incorporate the next few terms getting errors that decrease.